# Question about constructing an admissible ideal of a quiver of an algebra with the aid of a computer

Tags: rt.representation-theory, computer-science

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $A$  a finite-dimensional, basic, connected $k$-algebra. Then $A$ is Morita-equivalent to a quotient of a path algebra $kQ/I$ and $I$ is an admissible ideal.

I have the following question:

> > Is there an algorithmic / computational method (maybe already implemented in a CAS(?)), that is able to compute a basis of $I=$ ker $\varphi$ in terms of paths of the quiver of the algebra $A$?

Thank you very much.